# Query of Prometheus with Regex

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, rules, prometheus-alertmanager

Has anyone been able to help me?

I have a cluster where metrics from each namespace comes with a rash and I want to optimize a query with some regex to bring all namespaces to alert.

Ex.:

`producer_topic_metrics_producer_1_topic_/`**`namespace-rash`**`/`*`api_changes_total{namespace=1}`
`producer_topic_metrics_producer_1_topic`*`/`**`namespace-rash`**`/`*`api_changes_total{namespace=2}`
`producer_topic_metrics_producer_1_topic`*`/`**`namespace-rash`**`/`*`api_changes_total{namespace=3}`
`producer_topic_metrics_producer_1_topic`*`/`**`namespace-rash`**`/_api_changes_total{namespace=4}`

.....

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I found this documentation

https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

But I couldn't validate any regex for her that is accepted by prometheus.

Comment: Are you looking of `{__name__=~"producer_topic_metrics_producer_1_topic.*_api_changes_total"}`?

Comment: I opened a new question, now relating the procedure it gave me within a yaml manifest.

If possible can you help me there to sequence too?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76477360/alert-with-prometheus