# Alert with Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, metrics, rules, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a cluster where metrics from each namespace comes with a *rash* and I want to optimize a query with some regex to bring all namespaces to alert.

This is my configure of job:

```
 - job: my_job
    -----
   metric_relabel_configs:
   - source_labels:
     -  __name__
     regex:{__name__=~"process_.*_pod_bytes"}
     target_label: __name__
     replacement: 'process_namespace_pod_bytes'
```

This is my rule:

```
group:
  - name: Process for bytes of namespace
    rules:
    - alert: High process 
      expr: process_namespace_pod_bytes
      for: 1m
      labels:
        severity: Atention
      annotations:
        summary: High process usage.
```

but this forme not working!
Does anyone know if this is possible?

[Prometheus relabeling tricks](https://medium.com/quiq-blog/prometheus-relabeling-tricks-6ae62c56cbda)

[Prometheus Metrics: How to change the metric name?](https://alexandre-vazquez.com/prometheus-metrics-howto-change-name/#:%7E:text=__name__%20is%20a,that%20name%20since%20the%20beginning)

Comment: It looks like your relabeling is incorrect. Regex should be `process_.*_pod_bytes`, not `{__name__=~"process_.*_pod_bytes"}`

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! This was the problem. Now, my pod is running and my prometheus find this rule, but not working with correctly. Do I go open new Question, describe this problem for there. or better here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76483504/prometheus-with-rebalancing-not-firing