# Prometheus with rebalancing not firing

Tags: prometheus, metrics, rules, prometheus-alertmanager

The status of prometheus is running, in my prometheus the rule is inactive. but not is working the condition of rule!

Actual situation:

There is metric is being used as an example for my lab.

```
container_memory_usage_bytes > 0
```

```
container_memory_usage_bytes{beta_kubernetes_io_arch="amd64", beta_kubernetes_io_os="linux", id="/", instance="minikube", job="kubernetes-cadvisor", kubernetes_io_arch="amd64", kubernetes_io_hostname="minikube", kubernetes_io_os="linux", minikube_k8s_io_commit="ddac20b4b34a9c8c857fc602203b6ba2679794d3", minikube_k8s_io_name="minikube", minikube_k8s_io_primary="true", minikube_k8s_io_updated_at="2023_04_27T13_54_07_0700", minikube_k8s_io_version="v1.29.0"}  2679803904
......
```

This is my rule of prometheus

[Prometheus rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwO1h.png)

The rebalancing configured on manifest

```
metric_relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__name__]
          regex: container_memory_.*_bytes
          target_label: __name__
          replacement: 'container_memory_namespace_bytes'
          action: keep
```

This is alert rule.

```
groups:
      - name: test of relabeling
        rules:
        - alert: test of relabeling
          expr: container_memory_namespace_bytes > 0
          for: 1m
          labels:
            severity: ATENCAO
          annotations:
            summary: test of relabeling
```

My metric have value more high of zero, but my rule not working, in other words the status of rule continue inactive, when in fact it was supposed to be in firing.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

This task is continuation of task bellow:

[Alert with Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76477360/alert-with-prometheus?noredirect=1#comment134851784_76477360)

Comment: Please use text instead of images

Comment: my mistake, now was corrected.

I kept only the ones referring to application of Prometheus